# R Find the point of intersection of two lines connecting 4 coordinates

Tags: r

I apologize in advance if my code looks very amateurish. 
I'm trying to assign quadrants to 4 measurement stations approximately located on the edges of a town.

I have the coordinates of these 4 stations:

```
a  <- c(13.2975,52.6556)
b  <- c(14.0083,52.5583)
c  <- c(13.3722,52.3997)
d  <- c(12.7417,52.6917)
```

Now my idea was to create lines connecting the north-south and east-west stations:

```
line.1 <- matrix(c(d[1],b[1],d[2],b[2]),ncol=2)
line.2 <- matrix(c(a[1],c[1],a[2],c[2]),ncol=2)
```

Plotting all the stations the connecting lines looks allright, however not very helpful for analyzing it on a computer.

So I calculated the eucledian vectors for the two lines:

```
vec.1 <- as.vector(c((b[1]-d[1]),(b[2]-d[2])))

vec.2 <- as.vector(c((c[1]-a[1]),(c[2]-a[2])))
```

which allowed me to calculate the angle between the two lines in degrees:

```
alpha <- acos((vec.1%*%vec.2) / (sqrt(vec.1[1]^2+vec.1[2]^2)*  
          sqrt(vec.2[1]^2+vec.2[2]^2)))) * 180/pi
```

The angle I get for alpha is 67.7146°. This looks fairly good. From this angle I can easily calculate the other 3 angles of the intersection, however I need values relative to the grid so I can assign values from 0°-360° for the wind directions.

Now my next planned step was to find the point where the two lines intersect, add a horizontal and vertical `abline` through that point and then calculate the angle relative to the grid. However I can't find a proper example that does that and I don't think I have a nice linear equation system I could solve.

Is my code way off? Or maybe anyone knows of a package which could help me? It feels like my whole approach is a bit wrong.

Comment: You are saying "I don't have a linear equation system I could solve". Is there something preventing you from writing a system of two linear equations? If you know `acos`, I would assume you know how to write an equation of a straight line passing through two given points.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to calculate the intersection point, using line equations. Here is how.

The basic equation for two points is like this:

```
y - y_1 = (y_2-y_1/x_2-x_1) * (x-x_1)
```

If you make one for each  of the two lines, you can just substitute the fractions.

```
k.1 <- ((c[2]-a[2])/(c[1]-a[1]))
k.2 <- ((b[2]-d[2])/(b[1]-d[1]))
```

Reshaping the two functions you get a final form for  `y`:

```
y <- (((-k.1/k.2)*d[2]+k.1*d[1]-k.1*c[1]+d[2])/(1-k.1/k.2))
```

This one you can now use to calculate the `x`-value:

```
x <- ((y-d[2])+d[1]*k.2)/k.2
```

In my case I get

y = 52.62319

x = 13.3922

I'm starting to really enjoy this program!

Answer (score -1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) has a good article on finding the intersection between two line segments with an explicit formula. However, you don't need to know the point of intersection to calculate the angle to the grid (or axes of coordinate system.) Just compute the angles from your `vec.1` and `vec.2` to the basis vectors:

```
e1 <- c(1, 0)
e2 <- c(0, 1)
```

as you have done.

Comment: Not sure why the negatives - seems the right approach.  All you need to do is ascertain which quadrant each point is in, and the angle between the diagonal and the grid at the intersection will be the same as the angle between the line and the crossing of the relevant axis.  The slope of AC, for instance, is given by (Ya-Yc)/(Xa-Xc), which is enough to work out the angle of AC to the horizontal/vertical.  A drawing of the points is probably the easiest way to determine which quadrant each point lies in. If the question is more general, we may not even know which pairs are diagonally opposite.